# I am try to trigger alarm for Every day 12:00 am but why it is trigger after 10/20 minute later of 12:00 am?

Tags: java, android, function, calendar, repeatingalarm

```
   public void alarmUpdateForEveryDay(Context context) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewDayReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 50, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); 
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0); 
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); 
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() > c.getTimeInMillis()) {
            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1); // Add 1 day
        }

        long midnight = c.getTimeInMillis();

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, midnight, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
        
        Log.d("current_time", new Date(midnight).toString());
    }
```

I test with adjust the system time

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I recommend that you use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) for your date and time work and forget about the long outdated and troublesome `Calendar` and `Date` classes. You need something like `LocalDate.now().plusDays(1).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli()`.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the [documentation note](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager)

> Beginning with API 19 (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use.

You should use `setExact` and create a repeating mechanism in your app

Comment: Thank you for your valuable information,,